# Adding error checking to a Bash Shell Script number guessing game

Tags: bash, shell

I've had to create a number guessing game in a bash shell script for my Linux class, and that wasn't too difficult. Now I have to update the script to wrap the existing if block so that it runs "if and only if a numeric value is present", and I can't figure out how to do that. This is the first time I've ever had to do scripting, so I'm definitely a novice.

```
#!/bin/bash

min_number=1
max_number=10

my_number=$[ $RANDOM % ${max_number} + ${min_number} ]

echo -n "Guess a number between ${min_number} and ${max_number}: "
read number_guess

echo "My number is ${my_number}. You guessed ${number_guess}."

if [ ${number_guess} -eq ${my_number} ]; then
  echo "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
    else
      echo "Sorry, better luck next time!"
fi
exit 0
```

The instructions say: *Testing for not presenting input and not being a number might look like this:*

`if [ ! -z "${number_guess##*[!0-9]*}" ]; then`

But I can't figure out where in the code I'm supposed to put that to make it work with the rest of it. I've been messing with it for hours now, and I'm sure the solution is very simple, but I can't get it to do what I want it to do. I'm trying to make it echo "Please enter a valid number" when it's either a letter or a number not 1-10, but I can't figure it out. I did manage to get it to echo that earlier, but it would do it regardless of the number inputted, so I don't know. I'm **not** looking for someone to just do it for me, but an explanation or any kind of help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself, where in thie code shoud the prrovided block go, a) before you prompt the user for input? b) after you have done the comparison and decided Matched! or NotMatched? c ) after you have the user input but before you do the test? Once you have decided this, then you have to decide exactly where to put that test in the code, thinking about the flow of information and how you want it to work. Just go ahead and try each place and see what the resulst are. This is the beauty of shell scripting, easy testing. Also  decide what to do if the user has entered a non-number. Good luck!

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Note that the calculation for `my_number` will be incorrect if `min_number` is changed to something other than `1`.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not looking for someone to just do it for me, but an explanation or any kind of help at all would be greatly appreciated*

OK, but there's too much to say, [here there's reviewed code](https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/fa8a8daea7f26cd97335006b26b562b8)  in a modern Bash-y way, with sanitizing inputs in a more reliable & robust way (feel free to read it or not, I use best bash practices), but here is...

### Advice [image: note]

**[Best practice for sanitizing user input in arithmetic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/054)**

```
# POSIX
case $var in
    '' | *[!0123456789]*)
        printf '%s\n' "$0: $var: invalid digit" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

---

[Avoid shell injection](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#read_num.3B_echo_.24.28.28num.2B-1.29.29) in arithmetic expressions

---

Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. It can show you some pitfalls without human help

---

[image: warning] `$[...]` **is an obsolete, deprecated syntax for math. Don't use it**.

Use `$((...))` instead.

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`

Answer (score 1):

The proposed code snippet ...

```
if [ ! -z "${number_guess##*[!0-9]*}" ]; then
```

... has some issues when dealing with strings like `1a3` or `123_789`; *HINT*: try assigning different strings and then running `echo "${number_guess##*[!0-9]*}"` to see how this substituion behaves.

I'd probably opt for something a bit more verbose, eg:

```
# one of the following to strip out all non-numerics:

stripped="${number_guess//[!0-9]}"
stripped="${number_guess//[^0-9]}"

# plus one of the following to test for empty/no-response or a string that contains something other than numerics:

if [  -z "${stripped}" -o "${number_guess}" != "${stripped}"  ]; then
if [[ -z "${stripped}" || "${number_guess}" != "${stripped}" ]]; then
```

Then, to minimize changes to the current script, I'd probably integrate this into the current `if/else` block, eg:

```
stripped="${number_guess//[^0-9]}"

if [[ -z "${stripped}" || "${number_guess}" != "${stripped}" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Your guess ($number_guess) is not a valid number"
elif [ ${number_guess} -eq ${my_number} ]; then
  echo "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
else
  echo "Sorry, better luck next time!"
fi
```

**NOTE:** as mentioned in [Gilles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074499), `$[ ... ]` is an outdate form of doing math; I'll leave that to you and your instructor on if/how to proceed